# MySQL distinct select for emoji always return 1 emoji out of 2

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I have these emojis stored in a reaction column. `,`

If I run this query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT reaction 
 FROM chat_reactions 
WHERE chat_id = 593
```

it only selects the first one. My column's collation is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` but this issue doesn't happen for `❤️` (red love emoji)

How can I solve this?

My table and sample data..

```
                CREATE TABLE `chat_reactions` (
                `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                `reaction` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
                `profile_pic` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
                `full_name` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
                `chat_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
                `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
                `parrent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
                `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

                LOCK TABLES `chat_reactions` WRITE;
                /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `chat_reactions` DISABLE KEYS */;

                INSERT INTO `chat_reactions` (`id`, `reaction`, `profile_pic`, `full_name`, `chat_id`, `user_id`, `parrent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
                VALUES
                    (372,'?','https://letcheck.b-cdn.net/salman-cademys/cl9ca27uc0068kk1z25s4hfc7.jpg','সাদিয়া আফরিন ',593,340,NULL,'2022-10-17 10:32:16','2022-10-17 10:32:16'),
                    (394,'?','https://letcheck.b-cdn.net/salman-cademys/cl8vd1oxr00kc7a1z73befael.jpg','আমানী সাদউদ্দিন',593,309,NULL,'2022-10-17 17:46:08','2022-10-17 17:46:08'),
                    (396,'?','https://letcheck.b-cdn.net/salman-cademys/cl8vd1oxr00kc7a1z73befael.jpg','আমানী সাদউদ্দিন',593,309,NULL,'2022-10-17 17:46:08','2022-10-17 17:46:08');
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can check the edited question. I have added sample table and data

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following collation: `COLLATE utf8mb4_bin`

Test [code](https://www.db-fiddle.com/):

```sql
#bad results
SELECT emoji1,emoji2
 FROM( SELECT '' as `emoji1`, '' as `emoji2`) A
WHERE emoji1 = emoji2;

#good results
SELECT emoji1,emoji2
 FROM( SELECT '' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin as `emoji1`, 
              '' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin as `emoji2`) A
WHERE emoji1 = emoji2
```

Source Code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-mysql-database/39465494#39465494).

Answer (score 1):

`utf8mb4_unicode_ci` is a very old collation (from Unicode).  Newer ones:  `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` and (with the advent of MySQL 8.0) `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`.

The older collation(s) treated all Emoji as equal -- hence the `DISTINCT` treated them as the same.  Later version(s) treat them as unequal.  (You wanted 'unequal'.)

`utf8mb4_bin` has the side effects of treating all case and accent differences as different.  That is, `b` is not equal to `B`.  Not a problem for Emoji, but could be a problem if there is any text.

The red heart is more complex in that it involves two Unicode characters -- one as a "red" qualifier; the other as a "heart":

```
EFB88F ️,      VARIATION SELECTOR-16
E29DA4 ❤,      HEAVY BLACK HEART
```

The others need utf8mb4 (as you have), not utf8:

```
F09F988F ,      SMIRKING FACE
F09F9887 ,      SMILING FACE WITH HALO
```